# CSS spin coin animation glitch in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

When the animation reaches the edge of the coin, the animation starts to jerk. It's only appears in Safari browser. I tried to include vendor-prefixed properties like -webkit, I tried will-change, but it's still glitches. I believe there's a problem with box-shadow, I tried to add webkit to it as well, but still got nothing

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

:root {
  /* --lowlight: #111; */
  --side: #c2e635;
  --side-dark: #6ed92d;
  --coin-size: 136px;
}
/*
  everything above is positioning and variables.
  this is where the real fun begins...
*/

.coin {
  height: var(--coin-size);
  width: var(--coin-size);
  margin: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  will-change: transform;
}

.coin::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: var(--coin-size);
  width: var(--coin-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;

  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  will-change: transform, width, box-shadow, background-color;
}

.coin.silver::before {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
  background-image: url("https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-icon-m/p/4dd9406e-96d3-11e6-aa77-00163ec9f5fa/3927985343/java-development-kit-64-java-43-569305.png");
}

/* animation definitions */

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    width: var(--coin-size);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--side-dark);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  49.999% {
    width: 0.1rem;
    box-shadow: 0.05rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.1rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.15rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.2rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.25rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.3rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.35rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.4rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.45rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.5rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.55rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.6rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.65rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.7rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.75rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.8rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.85rem 0 0 var(--side),
      0.9rem 0 0 var(--side), 0.95rem 0 0 var(--side), 1rem 0 0 var(--side),
      1.05rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.1rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.15rem 0 0 var(--side),
      1.2rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.25rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.3rem 0 0 var(--side),
      1.35rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.4rem 0 0 var(--side), 1.45rem 0 0 var(--side),
      1.5rem 0 0 var(--side);
    transform: translateX(-14px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-14px);
    background-color: var(--lowlight);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

  50.001% {
    width: 0.1rem;
    box-shadow: -0.05rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.1rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.15rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.2rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.25rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.3rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.35rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.4rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.45rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.5rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.55rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.6rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.65rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.7rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.75rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.8rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.85rem 0 0 var(--side), -0.9rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -0.95rem 0 0 var(--side), -1rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.05rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -1.1rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.15rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.2rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -1.25rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.3rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -1.35rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.4rem 0 0 var(--side),
      -1.45rem 0 0 var(--side), -1.5rem 0 0 var(--side);
    transform: translateX(14px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(14px);
    background-color: var(--lowlight);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }

  100% {
    width: var(--coin-size);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 var(--side-dark);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
  <div class="coin silver"></div>
  <div class="coin silver"></div>
  <div class="coin silver"></div>
  </div>
```